# username with | pipe failing in windows FTP command line batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

When creating a batch file to process FTP commands, how do you enter the username when ftp/batch has an issue with the pipe.

Note: The dots/periods in the host and username are intential.

**Example**:

```
REM Connection information:
SET Server=my.server.com
SET UserName=my.server.com|my.username
SET Password=password


IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\FTPCommands" MD "%TEMP%\FTPCommands"
SET Commands="%TEMP%\FTPCommands\SendToFTP_commands.txt"


rem -- add username and password to commands file
ECHO %UserName%> %Commands%
ECHO %Password%>> %Commands%

FTP -d -i -s:%Commands% %Server%
```

**The error**:

"'my.username' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: try putting it in some form of quotes.  That usually fixes most of my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variable definition between double quotes and escape the pipe with a `^`:

```
set "UserName=my.server.com^|my.username"
```

Without the double quotes you'd need to escape the pipe twice: once when defining, and once when echoing the variable:

```
set UserName=my.server.com^^^|my.username"
```

`^^` is an escaped `^` and `^|` is an escaped `|`, so that you still have an escaped pipe when echoing the variable.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, the double quotes around the variable definition worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
SET "UserName=my.server.com|my.username"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
> "%Commands%" ECHO(!UserName! 
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ^| to escape the | symbol.

updated to correct for the escape character as pointed out by ansgar
Dos treats the | as the pipe symbol and trys to pipe the output of one command as the input of another. Hence your error. Because the pipe symbol is there the batch file interpreter expects my.server.com to be one program, that you are trying to pipe its output to my.username.

Comment: The backslash isn't an escape character in batch. This isn't bash.